# How to assign systemd to PID1

Tags: linux, systemd, kali-linux, virtualbox

I am trying to build a kalilinux environment on virtualbox and connect to it from a host computer using public key authentication for ssh.
However, after editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to enable public key authentication, I get the following error when using the `sytemctl restart ssh` command to reflect the edits.

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Failed to connect to bus: Host is down.
```

It appears that the problem is that systemd is not assigned to PID 1.
However, most of the solutions on the Internet are based on the wsl assumption (using Genie, which is available on GitHub) , and I could not find a solution for virtualbox.

I listed what I did.

1. Starting `sshd`
2. Edititing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
#PermintRootLogin prohibit-password
PermintRootLogin yes
```

3. Restarting `sshd` `systemctl restart ssh` success here
4. Private and public keys generated by teraterm
5. Copy public key to `. /.ssh/authorized_keys`.
6. Change access privileges

```
chmod -R 700 ./.ssh\
chmod -R 600 ./.ssh/authorized_keys
```

7. Edititing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
```

8. Restarting `sshd`, I failed here.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

PS
I found the cause of the error.
When I rebooted after building the environment, the problem of stopping at blackscreeen before the login screen, so I ran "apt install slim" to solve the problem.

After that, `sytemctl` was not available.

Comment: PID 1 is systemd unless you did something very weird. We can't help you if you don't tell us what weird thing you did.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have added what I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to build Kali yourself, the answer is, that you should boot with `systemd` as your init.

If that is to cryptical for you, I would recommend downloading the VirtualBox image from [kali.org](https://kali.org) and use that.

Comment: Thanks. The kali environment was already built using the kali.org image. What I'm trying to do is "systemctl restart ssh" to make an ssh connection with a public key.